# Coleus wilting, unsure why

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, leaves, indoors, coleus

My coleus plant was thriving about 2 weeks ago, it even flowered for the first time. I repotted it into a bigger pot and watered it, the soil is not dry and I don’t believe I over watered it, no sign of pests or anything.

[image]

Is it a goner or can it be saved?

Comment: Does that pot have drainage holes? If not, you might be encouraging fungus growth.

Comment: The pot does have drainage holes

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not a goner! I have grown many coleus plants and a few have looked like yours does but recovered. They are extremely resilient!

What went wrong? Well, it could just be transplant shock. When you repotted it, did a bunch of its roots rip out? If not it could still be transplant shock, just keep it watered and it will recover (maybe give it a little extra shade until it recovers). The only other thing it could be is over fertilizing (wilting like this in coleus is usually from under watering, transplant shock or over fertilizing). If you fertilized this new pot right after transplanting the coleus, I would recommend flushing out some of the fertilizer. The transplanting is rough enough on the plant, too much fertilizer will prevent the roots in shock from getting any water and the plant will wilt.

Comment: Thank you. A bunch of roots didn’t rip out and I have never fertilized it. Ive been keeping it watered but the leaves look like they are dying, it only gets sun for a couple hours in the morning. Should I move it out of the sun completely?

Comment: It seems like transplant shock then, coleus plants tend to very dramatic about transplant shock. Some of those leave will die, this is inevitable given the current status. Its a purple coleus so it should be sun-loving, I wouldn't think you would need to move it. Just be patient,  and don't overwater (might be tempting but don't, one deep watering until water comes out the bottom after transplant usually is enough).  The only other thing you could do to help it out (which you might not want to do and its okay not to), is cut off the flower. Flowering takes a lot of energy from the coleus.